# Detect Character encoding of unknown characters in Notepad++, and find/replace

Tags: notepad++, csv, utf-8

I have a CSV file in which I can see the following excerpt:

[image: screenshot]

I found these "black" characters by scrolling through the file. The file is huge(32 Mb). I am not sure what encoding the file is in; At the moment my Notepad++ is set to **"Encode in UTF-8"**. Also, when I try to do **ASCII -> HEX** (Plugins->Converter->ASCII -> HEX), I get the following output:

```
EDA0BDEDB88A
```

I would like to know:

- The encoding of these black characters.
- A regular expression to find similar occurrences inside my CSV file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The black characters are caused by Notepad++ not being able to map those byte sequences to a UTF-8 endpoint that can be visualized. As you might know, each character is stored as a series of bytes. In this case, those bytes are

In Hexadecimal

```
ED A0 BD ED B8 8A
```

In Binary

```
1110 1101 1010 0000 1011 1101 1110 1101 1011 1000 1000 1010
```

**This brings us to your questions.**

> What is the encoding of those black characters?

These are two UTF-8 characters. More specifically, the first one `ED A0 BD` is what is called a *'high surrogate'* the second one `ED B8 8A` is a *'low surrogate'*. Together, they form an [UCS surrogate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Character_Set_characters#Surrogates). Now that we know these are surrogate characters, we can [reverse the surrogate pair calculation](http://www.russellcottrell.com/greek/utilities/surrogatepaircalculator.htm).

If you look up these byte sequences in the [UTF-8 code-points table](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=55296&names=-), you will find that the first one maps to `U+D83D` and the second one maps to `U+DE0A`. Hence, the pair is D83D+DE0A. This maps to U+1F60A, which is..... *drumroll* [A smiley](https://www.google.com/search?q=U%2B1F60A&oq=U%2B1F60A&aqs=chrome..69i57.1144j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)!

So, the sequence you are looking at... is a smiley.

> A regular expression to find these characters

Now that we know this, we can use regex to find sequences like this like so:

```
\x{D83D}\x{DE0A}
```

And then for the question that you added in the comments later (this is an edit).

> is there any other utility I can find the characters which are not in
>   UTF8 in my csv file.

I have shown now that the characters in your file *are* UTF-8. However, to still answer your question, if you want a tool to manually try and find the encoding of some characters, you can use [this website](http://string-functions.com/encodedecode.aspx). Here you can enter some text, specify the encoding, and transform it into another encoding to see what characters it maps to.

Comment: is there any other utility I can find the characters which are not in UTF8 in my csv file. Kindly let me know

Comment: I figured it out! :) Check out my edit. The sequence you are looking at is a smiley! Problem solved. Case closed.